# Burn image file to multiple DVDs simultaneously

Tags: bash, debian

I have a question regarding a Linux bash script I'm working on. The script has a main routine (setting up and burning an .iso file to multiple SATA burners simultaneously); that also calls a separate script that does the actual burn with growisofs. This "subscript" is called as many times as there are burners, (x) or as many discs as needed (1 -> x). After several calls and burners have been started, the speed of the individual burns drops off dramatically. To fix this, I monitor and limit the number of burn processes to 2, only calling another instance upon completion of another. The speed still drops off even though the completed calls are no longer running. I am apparently missing something, since I'm assuming the level of used resources should remain fairly consistent. I know that simultaneously accessing the drives was a feature that disappeared after kernel 2.6.32. Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to my experience the bottleneck with multiple active /dev/sr has
vanished with Linux kernel 5.6. On older kernels and with libburn i
work around by using /dev/sg instead of /dev/sr. (I am not aware that
growisofs would offer the opportunity to use /dev/sg.)

About cause, various workarounds, and hopefully final relief see
https://dev.lovelyhq.com/libburnia/web/wiki/ConcurrentLinuxSr

Comment: Thank you so much for the info! I'll pursue this, see if I can work a kernel patch via the info in the link.